How to get stateDuration peaks on InfluxDB
I want to calculate total downtime of my devices that were greater than 5 minutes. Created a bucket that has 1s and 0s basically to represent if device is on or off.
I tried using stateDuration to count consecutive 0s in seconds.
This is my query:
`from(bucket: "machine_5_minute_stops")
 |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "equipment_measurement")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "speed")
 |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == 0, column: "turned_off")`

And it returns this:
return graph
How can i get turned_off on peaks? When the device turns on it's turned_off is -1, so I searched for a way to get -1s and then look for a point before it but could not find anything.
I also tried an approach of creating a filter to only return values of turned_off greater than 300, and then to try and find ends of lines on graph, but couldn't find anything on that either.
